# Connecting to an LDAP server via a Corporate Proxy

Tags: c, proxy, ldap, openldap

I'm using the [**OpenLDAP**](http://www.openldap.org/) API in C to connect to an external LDAP server and retrieve certain information.  However, the software needs to run behind a HTTP CONNECT corporate proxy.

OpenLDAP doesn't expose the underlying socket calls, so is there a way to use the OpenLDAP API to specify a proxy to go through?

```
LDAP* lp;
int res = ldap_initialize(&lp, "ldap://some-server.com:389");

... /* Can I specify a proxy server somehow here? */

ldap_sasl_bind_s(m_connection, "", LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE, &cred, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I looked through the manual and did some Googling and found `LDAP_OPT_URI` which is an option code that can be passed to `ldap_set_option`, along with a URI.  The manual describes the purpose of this option as :

> "Sets/gets a comma- or space-separated list of URIs to be contacted by
>   the library when trying to establish a connection."

That description seems a bit vague to me, but I thought it might sound like this could allow me to set a proxy URL.  However, I tried it and it has no effect anyway.

So, does OpenLDAP provide some way to connect via a proxy?

Comment: HTTP proxies are for HTTP. Your requirement is incorrect. Get it changed. Get the firewall changed if necessary.

Comment: No, you can tunnel through an HTTP server to another server which speaks any protocol

Comment: Only if your client can be told to use an HTTP proxy. Generally this only applies to browsers and other clients that are speaking HTTP.